# Zephyr BLE: Can a GATT Client connect to multiple GATT Servers

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

My question is very brief - In the Zephyr documentation, I couldn't find an answer to my question (which surprised me). **Is it possible for a GATT Client to connect to more than one GATT Server?**

Right now I am using two boards to compute something (one as a server and one as a client). Ideally, the result of the computation should be written to a characteristic on a *third* device, another GATT server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right I couldn't find this information easily but it is certainly possible to have multiple connections as I've tried this myself before. Many application and products built on Zephyr also rely on this feature. Generally speaking, there is no limit to the number of BLE connections that is imposed by the Bluetooth specification, but the limitation is usually dictated by the hardware. This is somehow mentioned in the Zephyr link below:-

https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/guides/bluetooth/overview.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was the case but I could not find an actual source that confirmed it. This helps a lot!